# assign @debug or @function @return value to variable in SCSS

Tags: css, sass, scss-mixins, css-calc

Is there any way to pass value to a **$variable** through **@function** or **@debug** I am using multiple Calc methods when it combines in mixins calc() inside calc() don't work.
*For example*

**Html**

```
<div class="misc"></div>
```

**SCSS**

```
@function cont-full() {
    @return calc(100vw - 32px);
}

$container-width: cont-full();
.misc {
    width: $container-width;
}
```

*When I inspect result in window it pints result like this*

```
.misc {
    width: calc(100vw - 32px);
}
```

*But what I want is calculated value for example **1520px** in browser like below*

```
.misc {
    width: 1520px;
}
```

Please guide Thanks.

Comment: When you use `calc()` it will not be calculated and converted to a value, it's a CSS function, not a SASS one. And SASS doesn't have any built-in function to do that either.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like below.

Create scss function

```
@function -rc($s, $m) {
  $result: #{$s*$m}px;
  @return $result;
}
```

Using the function

```
#logo_widget {
  position: absolute;
  width: -rc(220, 3);
  height: -rc(90, 3);
  margin: -rc(20, 3) -rc(40, 3);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

It generates below css

```
#logo_widget {
    position: absolute;
    width: 660px;
    height: 270px;
    margin: 60px 120px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0
}
```

Hope this will help you. Good luck!